# rqt-graph error

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed, uninstalled, reinstalled the rqt packages using "sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-rqt" i also did the same for the common-plugins. I keep getting the following:

nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~$ rosrun rqt-graph rqt-graph
[rospack] Error: package 'rqt-graph' not found

I tried running it in anew terminal as well... Still no luck. I am running this on a Jetson tx2. Any advice? Ive also tried the apt get update commands but theyre all up to date. Couldnt find much help looking through the other questions on rqt.

Just for my own eduification i looked in the file system /opt/ros/kinetic/share/rqt and the same for rqt-common-plugins. Both only contain a package.xml file.

also i do have a rqt-graph folder with a cmake folder, resource, package.xml and plugin.xml

EDIT: SO i reinstalled the full package. Same issue still occuring. Im not sure why im having this issue. Is it just that rqt is not compatible with the Nvidia Jetson?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267763/rqt-graph-error/) by [cmacks](https://answers.ros.org/users/31381/cmacks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-31**:
How did you install ROS? Did you setup your environment properly?

**Comment by [cmacks](https://answers.ros.org/users/31381/cmacks/) on 2017-07-31**:
I installed ros using the Jetson Hacks InstallRosTX2 package they made. I also did check that all of my files are in order. Ive run roswtf as well to check for any errors. I dont believe the normal ros install works on this board which is why they wrote a custom install script

**Comment by [aatzil](https://answers.ros.org/users/38311/aatzil/) on 2018-11-01**:
Were you ever able to figure out how to get the rqt command to work properly while using a jetson tx2? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you look at the [install script from the jetsonhacks GitHub repo](https://github.com/jetsonhacks/installROSTX2/blob/master/installROS.sh#L13), you'll notice on line 13 that it runs `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ros-base -y` which will install only the ROS base. The ROS base version does not include any GUI tools according to the [install page on the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/UbuntuARM#kinetic.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-Ubuntu.Installation-1).

After installing, run `rqt` to see if it works.

**Edit:** This may not apply, I re-read your question and I missed the part about you installing and re-installing `rqt` and `rqt-common-plugins`.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cmacks](https://answers.ros.org/users/31381/cmacks/) on 2017-07-31**:
omg... i didn't even see that. How would i go about installing full version then? Im assumign its just sudo apt-get intsall ros-kinetic-ros-desktop-full ?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-31**:
Yeah, that's one way to do it but that would install everything. `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-rqt ros-kinetic-rqt-common-plugins` should install it, but as you've said you already tried that.